# Button not clicking/calling function when pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was adding a new window in a bigger project and im having trouble with buttons... When you click on them when the program is running, there is no sign of them being pressed and nothing happens. Im pretty new to tkinter so if anyone could help that would be apprecated!

```
from tkinter import *

def window():

    def sign_up_clicked():
        return True
        print ('test')

    def log_in_clicked():
        return False
        print ('test')

    window = Tk()
    window.title('Welcome')
    window.geometry('480x200')

    welcome_lbl = Label(window, text='Welcome', font=('Arial', 26), fg='#71C2FE') #Label with text saying 'welcome' in light blue 
    welcome_lbl.place(x=15, y=10) #placing welcome label in top left of sign_up_window

    under_line_lbl = Label(window, text='_______________________', font=('Arial', 35), fg='#FFB56B') #orange line under blue for looks
    under_line_lbl.place(x=0, y=40)

    intro_lbl = Label(window, text='Please press login if you already have an account,\notherwiseyou can create an account by pressing sign-up. ', font=('Arial', 14, 'bold italic'), justify='left')#lable with text underlined and italics
    intro_lbl.place(x=10, y=90)

    sign_up_btn = Button(window, text='Sign up', relief='raised', width=6, font=('candara', 14), command=sign_up_clicked)
    sign_up_btn.place(x=10, y=130)

    log_in_btn = Button(window, text='Login', relief='raised', width=6, font=('candara', 14), command=log_in_clicked)
    log_in_btn.place(x=10, y=160)

    window.mainloop()

window()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning before your print statement is reached. Place `print('test')` first and then `return True`. When a function reaches a `return` it ends the execution of that function, hands back the value if your return is assigned one, and returns to the place it left off in your code.

Working example:

```
from tkinter import *

def window():

    def sign_up_clicked():
        print ('test')
        # returns control to mainloop
        return True

    def log_in_clicked():
        print ('test')
        # returns control to mainloop
        return False

    window = Tk()
    window.title('Welcome')
    window.geometry('480x200')

    welcome_lbl = Label(window, text='Welcome', font=('Arial', 26), fg='#71C2FE') #Label with text saying 'welcome' in light blue 
    welcome_lbl.place(x=15, y=10) #placing welcome label in top left of sign_up_window

    under_line_lbl = Label(window, text='_______________________', font=('Arial', 35), fg='#FFB56B') #orange line under blue for looks
    under_line_lbl.place(x=0, y=40)

    intro_lbl = Label(window, text='Please press login if you already have an account,\notherwiseyou can create an account by pressing sign-up. ', font=('Arial', 14, 'bold italic'), justify='left')#lable with text underlined and italics
    intro_lbl.place(x=10, y=90)

    sign_up_btn = Button(window, text='Sign up', relief='raised', width=6, font=('candara', 14), command=sign_up_clicked)
    sign_up_btn.place(x=10, y=130)

    log_in_btn = Button(window, text='Login', relief='raised', width=6, font=('candara', 14), command=log_in_clicked)
    log_in_btn.place(x=10, y=160)

    window.mainloop()

window()
```